# Warning: Division by zero with PHP multiplication line of code

Tags: php

I have this error message come up `Warning: Division by zero` and the line its referring to is

```
$rate = (($wins / ($wins + $lose)) * 100);
```

This only happens when a new user is registered as they start with 0 wins and 0 loses

I can kinda understand the error (how can you multiple 0?) but how do i fix this line of code?

The above code works out the players form and works very well

Comment: What is your question? You fix this code by fixing your equation. How should it be calculated if `$wins+$lose == 0`?

Comment: why dont u add a condition and check if the values are not 0 then do the calculation.

Comment: Just check to see if `$wins + $lose` is zero first.  `$rate = ($wins + $lose) === 0 ? 0 : (($wins / ($wins + $lose)) * 100);`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up', i'm sorry I kinda knew I would get down votes but been working on this error for the past few hours. i'm still learning.... but I appreciate all the replies :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handle the exception accordingly

```
if (($wins + $lose) != 0)
    $rate = (($wins / ($wins + $lose)) * 100);
else
    $rate = 0;
```

Comment: That's not an exception, it's an `if` statement.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i really appreciate it. its been driving me mad

Comment: @Chris Yes, not a technical exception, but still a special case that requires some extra code to handle the issue.